# Sample files to use Magento 2 API REST and SOAP

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, soap, sample

How can I use the REST and SOAP?

I'd like to have sample PHP files to use each one.

**I'm using the Magento 2.1.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these samples to do all things that you want using the API. There are 3 different methods, you can use anyone of these 3 methods.

> Remember to change the URL and method to what you want to do.

**API REST using OAuth based authentication**

```
<?php
function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{
    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);

    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);

    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}

// REPLACE WITH YOUR ACTUAL DATA OBTAINED WHILE CREATING NEW INTEGRATION
$consumerKey = '1fuj3asjsk4w3qb3cx44ik5ue188s30s';
$consumerSecret = 'lcey0h5uyt26slvtws5okaiqh8ojju5d';
$accessToken = 'b41sqrw1cfqh598yfoygd836c4ll3cr8';
$accessTokenSecret = 'lywj45gighqo3knl6bv6i61n2jf6iv0a';

$method = 'GET';
$url = 'http://magento.m2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/2';

//
$data = [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
];

$data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
    ]
]);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($result);
```

**API REST using OAuth based authentication**

```
<?php
$request = new SoapClient("http://magento.m2/index.php/soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1", array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));
$token = $request->integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken(array("username"=>"admin", "password"=>"GN2vKgfsszz43u"));

$opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.json_decode($token->result)
            )
        );

$wsdlUrl = 'http://magento.m2/soap/default?wsdl&services=directoryCurrencyInformationAcquirerV1';

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' => $context]);

$soapResponse = $soapClient->__getFunctions();
```

**API SOAP using Token based authentication**

```
<?php
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "mypassword");
$ch = curl_init("http://magento.m2/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CUsRLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$ch = curl_init("http://magento.m2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

[Reference of samples code.](https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/ecab668b80fece4d9acdb9c5358b3173)